# Plot shading in a contourplot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to create a contour plot like in the figure below. I basically have two lists, one with the function values and the other one with bools containing the information if a certain point is significant or not. 
I wasn't able to find a solution so far, help is much appreciated.
[image: Kyroelae et al., 2013]

Comment: Can use [patterns](http://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#hatching-patterns-in-filled-contour-plots-with-legends) in a subsequent call?

Comment: It is kind of a workaround, but I like this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146370/plotting-points-on-a-contourf-plot/22148587#22148587. Additional to the significance it also carries information regarding the resolution, which I find quite beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for a good way to do this myself in matplotlib but unfortunately have not found a good solution. However, you could use the excellent [pyngl](http://www.pyngl.ucar.edu/) toolbox to make such plots. Take a look at the examples site [here](http://www.pyngl.ucar.edu/Examples/gallery.shtml) or you could use the actual NCAR Command Language (NCL) found [here](http://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Applications/coneff.shtml).