# Plotting points on a contourf plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Following a earlier question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170184/plot-shading-in-a-contourplot-with-matplotlib)) I'd now like to just plot a point to every grid value which is significant. In the moment I do it like this

```
ax.contourf(x, y, z)
for i in x:
    for j in y:
        if significant[i, j]==True: ax.plot(i, j, 'bo')
```

which is obviousliy really bad as it is very slow. Is there some simple (fast) solution for this problem? Note that x and y don't have the same length and I need x to be of variable length.

Comment: I guess that [`ax.scatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) will do.

Comment: I already tried it. It requires len(x)=len(y) though, so at least it doesn't work without further adjustment.

Comment: Are `x` and `y` 2D arrays? By the way: your are plotting `ax.plot(x, y, 'bo')` (all the x and y arrays) every time `significant[i.j]==True`. Is it a typo?

Comment: Was a typo, tanks. x and y are 1D arrays, i.e. x is the time axis and I'd like to plot variable time periods, hence the variable length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the loop only where significant is true:

```
for i, j in zip(*np.where(significant)):
     ax.plot(i, j, 'bo')
```

Or, if x and y are not arange-like:

```
for i, j in zip(*np.where(significant)):
     ax.plot(x[i], y[j], 'bo')
```

np.where will return a tuple with two elements, the first and the second index of the nonzero elements.

Comment: Definitely more elegant and also much faster, thanks. The for-loop didn't work for me though, I had to adjust it:  for i, j in zip( np.where(significant)[0], np.where(significant)[1] )

Comment: Which numpy version are you using? I have re-checked it and it does work:
significant = np.zeros((5,4), dtype=np.bool);
significant[1, 3] = True;
significant[3, 2] = True;
for i, j in np.where(significant): print i, j

Comment: I use version 1.6.2. If I want to run over two indices at the same time I have to use zip(): a = b = range(5); for i, j in zip(a, b): print i, j. Can you please try to set mor then 2 values True, because for exactly to it works for me too but that is just a coincidence as I also run over to indices.

Comment: Good catch, editing my answer to correct it.
Note that using zip(* ) you can avoid running np.where twice.